# Odoo 10 - Cannot unblock a work center in dashboard, neither on individual work orders

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

my work center is blocked :
[image]

But when I try to unblock, I always get this error : (the same error happens if I try to unblock the work order).
Please let me know if more details needed, I am new in stack overflow.
Thanks in advance

Odoo Server Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\\Dropbox\\myProjects\\Python\\Odoo10\\odoo\\http.py", line 642, in \_handle_exception
return super(JsonRequest, self).\_handle_exception(exception)
File "D:\\Dropbox\\myProjects\\Python\\Odoo10\\odoo\\http.py", line 684, in dispatch
result = self.\_call_function(\*\*self.params)
File "D:\\Dropbox\\myProjects\\Python\\Odoo10\\odoo\\http.py", line 334, in \_call_function
return checked_call(self.db, \*args, \*\*kwargs)
File "D:\\Dropbox\\myProjects\\Python\\Odoo10\\odoo\\service\\model.py", line 101, in wrapper
return f(dbname, \*args, \*\*kwargs)
File "D:\\Dropbox\\myProjects\\Python\\Odoo10\\odoo\\http.py", line 327, in checked_call
result = self.endpoint(\*a, \*\*kw)
File "D:\\Dropbox\\myProjects\\Python\\Odoo10\\odoo\\http.py", line 942, in __call__
return self.method(\*args, \*\*kw)
File "D:\\Dropbox\\myProjects\\Python\\Odoo10\\odoo\\http.py", line 507, in response_wrap
response = f(\*args, \*\*kw)
File "D:\\Dropbox\\myProjects\\Python\\Odoo10\\addons\\web\\controllers\\main.py", line 899, in call_button
action = self.\_call_kw(model, method, args, {})
File "D:\\Dropbox\\myProjects\\Python\\Odoo10\\addons\\web\\controllers\\main.py", line 887, in \_call_kw
return call_kw(request.env\[model\], method, args, kwargs)
File "D:\\Dropbox\\myProjects\\Python\\Odoo10\\odoo\\api.py", line 689, in call_kw
return call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
File "D:\\Dropbox\\myProjects\\Python\\Odoo10\\odoo\\api.py", line 680, in call_kw_multi
result = method(recs, \*args, \*\*kwargs)
File "D:\\Dropbox\\myProjects\\Python\\Odoo10\\addons\\mrp\\models\\mrp_workcenter.py", line 160, in unblock
times.write({'date_end': fields.Datetime.now()})
File "D:\\Dropbox\\myProjects\\Python\\Odoo10\\odoo\\models.py", line 3592, in write
self.\_write(old_vals)
File "D:\\Dropbox\\myProjects\\Python\\Odoo10\\odoo\\models.py", line 3823, in \_write
self.recompute()
File "D:\\Dropbox\\myProjects\\Python\\Odoo10\\odoo\\models.py", line 5378, in recompute
recs.browse(ids).\_write(dict(vals))
File "D:\\Dropbox\\myProjects\\Python\\Odoo10\\odoo\\models.py", line 3693, in \_write
cr.execute(query, params + (sub_ids,))
File "D:\\Dropbox\\myProjects\\Python\\Odoo10\\odoo\\sql_db.py", line 154, in wrapper
return f(self, \*args, \*\*kwargs)
File "D:\\Dropbox\\myProjects\\Python\\Odoo10\\odoo\\sql_db.py", line 231, in execute
res = self.\_obj.execute(query, params)
NumericValueOutOfRange: integer out of range
```

I was expecting the work center would became unblocked, and all the work orders related to it.
I am not able to find the problem, the export of tables all seem OK

Answer (score 0):

When unblocking a workcenter Odoo will set "now" as `date_end` to every productivity record (model `mrp.workcenter.productivity`) without an end date belonging to the workcenter. That's the part in your traceback with "unblock" at the end.

That itself triggers a recomputation of the `duration` field on the productivity records. If i'm not wrong the duration is computed in minutes as difference of `date_end` and `date_start`. It seems there are records producing very high numbers.

That could be because you either have very bad data on those records or you have implemented another computation method which is computing wrong.